# SPARQL Return records from second Query ONLY IF no records in recordset from execution of First Query

Tags: semantics, rdf, sparql

I am new to SPARQL and so would appreciate help with this.

I have two queries to run. The one returns records from a source. However in the case that no records are returned in the first case, I would like to return records from the second query.

In SQL SERVER, I Would probably have to do something like

```
SELECT FIRSTAME, LASTNAME, DOB, CLASS 
 FROM TABLENAME 
   WHERE CLASS ="FIRSTCLASS"

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0

     SELECT FIRSTAME, LASTNAME, DOB, CLASS 
 FROM TABLENAME 
   WHERE CLASS ="SECONDCLASS"
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just dispatch two queries in your application?  There is no conditional logic in SPARQL.  SPARQL 1.1 does include subqueries, but I'm not sure if you can replicate what you want with that.  I'd suggest just using two separate queries, and keep the business logic in your code rather than in the query.

Comment: If it must be a single query (for transactionality reasons for e.g.) then you could add FILTER(?class = <FirstClass> || ?class = <SecondClass>), or use a UNION, and apply the logic in your application.